# initWithCoder: method not printing out to screen correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having trouble with the initWithCoder: method. In the line which reads

```
item.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item for %@", list.name];
```

"Item for" does not print out to the screen. list.name prints out fine.

What is the problem?

```
#import "AllListsViewController.h"
#import "Checklist.h"
#import "ChecklistViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"

@interface AllListsViewController ()

@end

@implementation AllListsViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_lists;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        _lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

        Checklist *list;

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Birthdays";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Groceries";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Cool Apps";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"To Do";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        for(Checklist *list in _lists) {
            ChecklistItem *item = [[ChecklistItem alloc] init];
            item.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item for %@", list.name];
            [list.items addObject:item];
        }

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_lists count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = checklist.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowChecklist" sender:checklist];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if  ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowChecklist"])
    {
        ChecklistViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;

        controller.checklist = sender;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddChecklist"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        ListDetailViewController *controller = (ListDetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.checklistToEdit = nil;

    }
}

#pragma mark - ListDetailViewControllerDelegate methods

- (void)listDetailViewControllerDidCancel:(ListDetailViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist
{
    NSInteger newRowIndex = [_lists count];
    [_lists addObject:checklist];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishEditingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist
{
    NSInteger index = [_lists indexOfObject:checklist];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = checklist.name;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListNavigationController"];

    ListDetailViewController *controller = (ListDetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.delegate = self;
    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];
    controller.checklistToEdit = checklist;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

Comment: Where are you trying to output item.text to the screen?

Comment: Am trying to output to a table view on iPhone. Right now there are four cells, each reading Birthdays, Groceries, Cool Apps, To Do. Would like it to read Item for Birthdays, Item for Groceries, etc.

Comment: Two things. First, in your for loop in initWithCoder, you're adding a CheckList object (called "item") to a CheckList object ([list.items addObject:item]). Is this what you mean to do? Second, I don't see anywhere in your cellForRowAtIndexPath where you try to access list.items and then item.text, so of course you're not going to see the  "Item for".

Answer (score 0):

You're not displaying the proper object if you want the string with `Item for ...` to be displayed on your cell. Currently, from what I can see, your data structure looks like this:

```
_lists (Array):
[
    list (Checklist):
    {
        name (String): @"Birthdays", // 0
        items (Array):
        [
            item (ChecklistItem):
            {
                text (String): @"Item for Birthdays" // 1
            }
        ]
    },
    list (Checklist):
        etc.

]
```

It appears that you're setting your cell's `textLabel` to `_lists[indexPath.row].name`, which I've commented at `// 0` in the structure above. If you're wanting to get to the `Item for ...` (commented at `// 1`) string, you'll need to do:

```
_lists[indexPath.row].items[0].text
```

I'm assuming that it will be at index 0, unless you happen to be adding other data to what I assume to be the `NSMutableArray *items` object in your `ChecklistItem`.